# What is the value range of the parameter optimize-runs when running the solidity compiler?

Tags: solidity, solc, compiler

I would like to know what the allowed value range of the parameter optimize-runs is when running the Solidity compiler. I didn't find the answer in the official document of Solidity.

Comment: Probably `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, but you shouldn't be needing such a high value, since it will most likely not improve anything at that point (while increasing you compilation time). Side note: Etherscan verification API, doesn't allow anything higher than 999999, so if you plan to use this API after deployment, than you might want to take this fact into consideration.